# Win10 bluetooth mouse is paired but not working

Tags: windows-10, drivers, mouse, bluetooth

Today I buy Omega Bluetooth 2.1 + EDR Laser Mouse. 
I do everything like on my last mouse.

Everything is ok, mouse is paired in bluetooth settings, showed in device manager. But when I try to move him nothing is happening. Mouse not work!

**What I do**:

1. I turn on mouse (off to on)
2. Turn on bluetooth on pc
3. Press and hold connect button on mouse
4. I get discoveable device in bluetooth list
5. Click on avable buetooth mouse and clic PAIR
6. After few second mous show progress bar belowe and start installing drivers
7. After that status is changet to CONNECTED and after few second is changed to PAIRED

I also try troubleshooting, and also try to restart bluetooth service, and also try to update driver in device manager, restart pc ....

And still not working I really don't know whay and what is problem what I miss to do ?

**Screenshot 1**
[image: Bluetooth screenshot]

**Screenshot 2**

[image: Bluetooth screenshot]

**Screenshot 3**

[image: Bluetooth screenshot]

Comment: Do you have anything else Bluetooth to try on this machine? It's hard to tell if its Windows or the device if that's the only one you have.

Comment: I do not try to ther machine. I will do that to see maybie mouse not work!!!

Answer (score 1):

I advise you try your mouse on another computer or laptop to see if the lagging problem continues. If your mouse works well, you need to reinstall Mouse driver by yourself.

- open Device Manager.
- locate Mouse and other pointing device and select it.
- Uninstall it
- restart your computer. Windows 10 will automatic update Mouse driver

**You can also try Set the touchpad to No Delay**

- Settings > Devices > Mouse & Touchpad.
- select Touchpad section.
- set the delay before clicks to No delay (always on).

Seen more Windows 10 Mouse Fix: http://howtoinstallwindows10.com/windows-10-mouse-lag-fix